# How to remove symbols between chars using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string 
 a="**a+f**(kp-ol)-g(jp-nl)+h(jo-nk)-**b+e**(kp-ol)-g(ip-ml)+h(io-mk)+**c-e**(jp-nl)"

now I want to remove +/- between chars to look like the chars are multiplied.
(ie)
In dis string take a+f to be transformed to af..remove + in between...Similarly for whole string.

can anybody suggest a solution using regex

Comment: You want to remove them between characters outside of parentheses only?

Comment: yup only outside parentheses..not inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z])[+-](?=[a-zA-Z])(?![^(]*\))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/84). Replace by `$1`.

This captures a letter before any `+-` sign and also uses a lookahead to assert that "it has a letter after it". To make sure it is not inside parenthesis another lookahead is put which asserts "there should not be a `)` which has no `(` behind it". The captured letter is replaced afterwords as it is stored in `$1`.

You could use positive lookbehind instead of a capturing group.

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])[+-](?=[a-zA-Z])(?![^()]*\))
```

Java regex would be,

```
"(?<=[a-zA-Z])[+-](?=[a-zA-Z])(?![^()]*\\))"
```

And then replace the matched `+` or `-` symbols by an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Surround `+` or `-` by word boundary `\b` which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
String s = "a+f(kp-ol)-g(jp-nl)+h(jo-nk)-b+e(kp-ol)-g(ip-ml)+h(io-mk)+c-e(jp-nl)";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\b[-+]\\b", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
af(kpol)-g(jpnl)+h(jonk)-be(kpol)-g(ipml)+h(iomk)+ce(jpnl)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/4)

To match all the `+` or `-` symbols surrounded by word boundaries which are present at the outside of paranthesis.

```
"\\b[-+]\\b(?![^()]*\\))"
```

Example:

```
String s = "a+f(kp-ol)-g(jp-nl)+h(jo-nk)-b+e(kp-ol)-g(ip-ml)+h(io-mk)+c-e(jp-nl)";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\b[-+]\\b(?![^()]*\\))", ""));
```

Output:

```
af(kp-ol)-g(jp-nl)+h(jo-nk)-be(kp-ol)-g(ip-ml)+h(io-mk)+ce(jp-nl)
```